# Aliens Invade and Enslaves Humans. Hero sends A-bomb thru transport to alien planet

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

I just found this site in my search to try and find a book I read many years ago (pre 1985?). I still remember it, especially the ending. Basically, it's about aliens having conquered earth and enslaving humans for years. Our hero fights for liberation, which I don't remember much of, but I do remember that he wins in the end by utilizing Alien technology against them. He places an A-bomb on the transport platform and sends it back to the alien's home planet where it detonates and destroys the aliens. Any ideas?

Comment: Did it really, really suck? If so, then it was probably *Battlefield Earth*.

Comment: The book was an okay (not great), pulpy space opera. It was the movie that sucked.

Comment: The general idea of beaming bombs directly to their targets is used several times in SF, for instance in "Loophole" by Clarke, and "No War, or Battle's Sound" by Harrison.

Comment: It's also use in Kevin O'Donnell's ORA:CLE. Did the aliens have wings?

Comment: @SQB, not to mention Star Gate, the movie.

Comment: I'm the guy who had the Q, but I'm new to this site & didn't see how to respond beyond just making this comment. So I want to thank the responders. Y'all sure know your stuff. I checked the possibilities, & it was indeed Battlefield Earth. My first reaction was "I can't believe I read something back then that was over 1000 pages." Then, "It was made into a movie? Wow, I was totally out of it." Finally, "Oh no, it was an L. Ron Hubbard novel? NOOOOOOO!" I just remember I liked it, not sure I would now, but it definitely left an impression on my young mind at the time. Thanks for the help folks.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents, I would have like *Battlefield Earth* much better if he had dropped the last 1/3 of the novel (pretty much everything after the liberation of Earth).

Comment: Worth noting that the reason the plot descibed above is so destructive in Battlefield Earth is that the alien invaders' home world has an atmosphere made up of some gas that ignites, chain reaction style, when in the presence of radiation, thus a single A bomb is able to wipe out the entire planet...

Answer (score 9):

This is L. Ron Hubbard's [Battlefield Earth](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield_Earth_(novel)).
There was also [a movie made from it](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XhNuXvlCTTc), but you can not put a 1100 page book in a 2 hour movie.

[image: book cover]

Comment: That cover painting betrays spectacular anatomical ignorance!

Comment: Especially not when the book is crap to begin with.

Comment: @Shadur - I actually thought the book was quite amusing.  Absolutely preposterous, of course, but as long as you can ignore the thinly veiled attacks on various groups (pyschiatrists, bankers) and the bizarre made-up science it's actually quite a fun read.

Comment: @Shadur crap??? The fact I remember this book almost 30 years after reading it proves the opposite. One of the best.

Comment: @shadowwizard Hubbard was a lousy writer and a worse con artist. There are plenty of crappy books I remember thirty years after first reading them, mostly because when I read them when I was younger, stupider and had worse tastes in literature than I do now.