# Pre-1987 sci-fi paperback regarding invasion of earth, resistance by Johnny, reorganization of earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Once Earth is subjugated, Johnny (I think) becomes the leader of the resistance and starts to reorganize Earth's government and take the battle to the aliens. Paperback written pre-1987.

Comment: This is a bit sparse. Can you offer any more information about the events of the novel, who/what the aliens were, their motivation for invading, how we fought back?

Comment: @Richard we fought back using Slim Whitman.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72899/aliens-invade-and-enslaves-humans-hero-sends-a-bomb-thru-transport-to-alien-pla / see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82834/movie-where-earth-is-conquered-and-humanity-are-cavemen-slaves for film adaptation

Answer (score 5):

The book is [Battlefield Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield_Earth_%28novel%29) published 1982, and the hero is Jonnie Goodboy Tyler, who starts off as a slave and then rebels.

Comment: I've heard very good things about the film adaptation.

Comment: The book is a fine bit of sci-fi trash for a 10-year-old, and obviously I do still remember reading it, but I'm not sure it would bear revisiting...

Comment: Don't troll the poor guy. The film was awarded a record-setting nine Razzies, including "Worst Picture of the Decade" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield_Earth_%28film%29#Golden_Raspberry_Awards).