# Film: Aliens destroyed civilisation on Earth, captured some tribal people to train as pilots(?), resistance ensued

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember aliens watching the tribe to know what humans eat. Hunters captured a rat, so after capture of the tribe, aliens gave them rats as food.

Some of humans were chosen to be implanted knowledge. After returning from one of procedure, human started teaching  others ("this is a triangle").

There was a simulation of flying small craft. In the first attempt s pilot decided to kill an alien by hitting the ground (but it of course was just a simulator).

Some time later humans found military planes(?). They trained fighter pilots in full-cabin simulators.
I remember scene with those planes hovering behind bridge or something to hide from alien fighters.

Film ended with one of humans sacrificing himself by teleporting on top of a nuke to the alien home planet. Somehow explosion caused chain reaction that destroyed all atmosphere on that planet(?).

Comment: Sounds very like "Battlefield earth", but I've only read the book, never seen the film.

Comment: Almost certainly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82834/movie-where-earth-is-conquered-and-humanity-are-cavemen-slaves

Comment: @BinaryWorrier It's definitely [Battlefield Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield_Earth_(film))

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - Our policy is that [we don't vote to close as a dupe until OP has confirmed that they're the same property](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774).

Comment: @Valorum: I wasn't aware, thanks for the info.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - No worries. Every day's a school day on SFF:SE

Comment: @BinaryWorrier. Repeat after me. There is no film