# Story where Earth is saved by sending nuclear bomb to alien race controlling it

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a science fiction story as teenager, over 20 years ago, these are the details I remember:

- Earth is controlled by an alien race who conquered it.
- The situation is really desperate, the technology gap is huge.
- Earth people became mostly slaves, sending materials to the home planet of the invaders.
- The small resistance group on Earth succeeds to send a nuclear bomb to the invader's home planet, causing them to retreat from Earth after it caused major damage, maybe even destroyed the whole planet in a chain reaction of some kind.

I think this was written by Robert Heinlein, but not sure about it.

Can anyone help me remember what story this might be?

Comment: Battlefield Earth by L Ron hubbard?

Comment: @Valorum whoa... Ron/Robert, Hubbard/Heinlein - no wonder I got confused with the name a bit. But yeah, looking now on the story details that is the one. 1050 pages (!!), didn't remember it was so much. (Would have added that detail to the question, lol. :))

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72899/aliens-invade-and-enslaves-humans-hero-sends-a-bomb-thru-transport-to-alien-pla (about the book, as in this question)

Comment: @Otis whoa.. now that's 1000% dupe, thanks. :)